# Как определить в базе данных строки, которые никогда не использовались?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Здравствуйте. Есть бд mysql, использую Hibernate. Есть ли такое средство, позволяющее определить записи в базе, которые ни разу не подходили ни под один запрос? Или если подходили, то когда?

Answer (score 3):

Добрый вечер!

К сожалению, сам MySQL не имеет подобных механизмов. Но вы вполне можете реализовать желаемое программно на уровне вашего приложения. Например, создать столбец used типа TINYINT, в который при обращении будет всегда записываться единица. Так вы сможете узнать, изменялась/запрашивалась ли запись в БД.

Так же большинство ORM создают столбцы created_at, updated_at и deleted_at, куда записывают время создания, обновления или удаления соответственно. Можете воспользоваться схожим механизмом.

Ещё одна деталь: вы можете распознать, использовалась ли когда-либо таблица. Сделать это можно так, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014796/mysql-find-unused-tables).